# Which memory is Dask showing here?

Tags: dask

After running the dask-worker, I see the following output with 40.53 GB of memory. Is the 40.53 GB referring to the distributed ram here or the disk memory? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That refers to the amount of memory that Dask intends to use on this particular worker before spilling excess results to disk.  This doesn't refer to disk, nor does it refer to distributed memory.  It refers only to the physical ram on this particular worker.  You can modify it with the `--memory-limit` keyword.

```
dask-worker scheduler-address:8786 --memory-limit VALUE
```

By default this is 60% of the physical memory reported by the `psutil` library.